# PHP French characters

Tags: php, character, french

Can someone, please, help me we the next one...

I try to make **Read More** and **Read Less**, but the problem is if I limit text (in French language)
and limited text ends with character 'é' for example 'de qualité' it show me this character at the end of the word '�'(instead of 'é'). But if I don't limit and use whole text, in that case it show that character correctly. For example:

`$text = "de qualité de"`

Result will be:

`de qualit�...Read More`

and

`de qualité de...Read Less`

How can' I fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Use `mb_*` functions.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks a lot.